# お粥を食べたので、もう寝るつもりです

Tags: meaning, nuances

Context:

> 今日は夕方から体調が悪くて、吐き気がありました。仕事が終わってからお粥を食べた**ので**、もう寝るつもりです。

I fell it is a little weird that if I translate "ので" to "because", as:

"After the work is finished, because I had some o-kayu, I'm going to bed."

(I suppose "から" mean "after/then" here, but not "cause".)

Is there a better way to translate "ので" explicitly?

And someone gave me a idea that 'ので' shows not only reason/cause but also grounds/motif.

(I have tried to distinguish "reason/cause" from "grounds/motif", but nothing has worked.)

Does "ので" should mean "grounds/motif", but not "because" in this context?

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by "grounds/motif"?

Comment: I guess it may be less weird if you think it simply as "so".

Comment: Sorry to can't explain grounds/motif, may be it is a useful link: https://www.writingtips.cc/reason-vs-ground-vs-argument-vs-proof/?

Answer (score 1):

I see the use of ので here as implying that the first event has some effect on the second event. The underlying relation could be

- the speaker thinks that eating is the only thing left to do before sleeping (Note that it's 食べた and 寝る - there is a strict temporal order, and the present is between the two.)
- the speaker thinks that being not hungry makes it easier to sleep

Comment: Thanks for the analysis and supposition! It is very useful for me to understand.

Answer (score -1):

As I'm no Japanese linguist, I think it's better to just think of ので as a formal way of saying から. Makes life easier for me.

Comment: But that changes meaning of this sentence (and many others). ので and から is different. Not saying that it doesn't share nuance, but still it's different. And it's not formal way; Formal sentence uses both by situation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about ので and から!